# Conversões indevidas nos títulos das postagens

Tags: bug

Fui corrigir o título de uma postagem ([esta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/151120/revisions)) que tinha aspas inglesas no titulo:

> [image: Print ampliado do Diff mostrando aspas inglesas sendo substituidas por aspas duplas normais]

Ocorre que a edição consta do histórico, mas o sistema do site está substituindo as aspas novamente na exibição (este post aqui, enquanto o problema persistir, tem um exemplo no título).

Sempre tivemos este problema no corpo das perguntas (vindos de copy & paste de WordPress e similares), que precisam de revisão constante.

Irônico é que o nosso próprio engine faz isso. Somos um site sobre programação. Substituição automática de caracteres é extremamente indesejável.

**Edit**: Originalmente o post era sobre aspas, mas tem outras conversões indevidas:

Neste post, o source é `<!-- até -->`, e foi modificado indevidamente:

> [image: dois sinais de negativo convertidos em um travessão]

No meu ver, isso é um [bug](/questions/tagged/bug). Espero que a empresa dê a roupagem correta para o problema :)

[image: Tirinha "bug", "feature" e "by design", mostrando um inseto nu, um com roupa social, e o terceiro com roupa social em péssimo estado]

Comment: Isso traz algum tipo de problema? Digo, se for no código eu entendo, mas sendo no texto ou título...?

Comment: @RafaelTavares ao olhar não se sabe se foi um erro de digitação ou não, se o título estiver se referindo a código. Inclusive, na pergunta que eu linkei (a que fiz a edição) sequer faz sentido serem aspas inglesas. pois ele se referia a string vazia.

Comment: Featured by Wix.

Comment: Mais um pra lista de memes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iu5D5.jpg

Comment: @Bacco parece que foi corrigido

Comment: @RafaelTavares é que com a mudança de fonte o " ficou parecido com “ e ”, mas o problema permanece. Acho que vai precisar de um zoom no comment pra ver direito :)  https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQ5pA.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foi corrigido. Mesmo títulos criados antes da correção parecem estar "normais" agora.

Esse problema já havia sido reportado no Metão algumas vezes, e hoje foi marcado como resolvido. Citando [uma resposta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369331/818993) do [Yaakov Ellis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/51/yaakov-ellis):

> We have now disabled all Smarty-like modifications text in titles.
>
> From now on, the title text saved for the post is the title text that will be displayed.
>
> If folks want em-dashes (`ALT-0151`) and fancy quotes (`ALT-0145` through `-0148`) to appear in titles, they are welcome to add them. But we won’t convert it automatically any longer.
>
> That said, we have no plans to introduce markdown in titles.

Alguns exemplos de títulos que agora funcionam bem podem ser verificados em:

- [O que significa " | " em TypeScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/419420/100416) - aspas duplas
- [Split em aspas simples '](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/280657/100416) - aspas simples
- [Alterar --push-option com hooks](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/515459/100416) - duplo hífen
- [Uma query MySQL, com `crases` vs sem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/79846/100416) - acento grave

Comment: Nossa, quase 11 anos pra corrigir. E eu achando que [isso aqui](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125148/401803) tinha sido demorado...